# Aggregate query in fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

```
select T.Id, count(Th.ampount)
from TH, T
where Th.Tid= T.id
group by T.Id
```

How to write above query using fluent nhibernate. I don't want to use CreateSQLQuery().

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is a mapping tool, the query mechanisms can be HQL, ICriteria, QueryOver or Query.  Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Found answer in post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399448/nhibernate-aggregate-query-for-one-to-many-relation

Answer (score -1):

```
session.QueryOver<TH>()
    .JoinAlias(th => th.Ts, () => tAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(th => th.Id)
        .SelectCount(() => tAlias.amount)
        // or did you mean
        .SelectSum(() => tAlias.amount)
    )
    .List<object[]>();
```