# How to add groupby in query over nhibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, nhibernate, queryover

How can I add groupby Id to this nhibernate code because I'm new with it and there is many way but none work for me.

```
.Select(Projections.Sum(() => ServiceOrderItem.WorkTime), 
    Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property(
        () => ServiceOrder.Id).WithAlias(() => TechnicianWorkTime.Id))
    )
```

There will be more in ProjectionList...

Comment: Very difficult to answer without whole query, class definitions and expected result. Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414207/1236044

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `SelectList` for it:

```
query.SelectList(list => list
  .SelectGroup(() => ServiceOrder.Id)
  .SelectSum(() => ServiceOrderItem.WorkTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well:

```
objQuery = objQuery.SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup((x => x.Id)));
```